# Arm Template - Why am I getting an error saying resource is not defined in template?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have a parent arm template that uses various linked component templates. The webApp I am creating requires a dependency on a service plan but after adding a dependency like the one in the dependencies section of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates?tabs=azure-powershell) I keep getting an error: `'The resource 'Microsoft.Resources/deployments/NovaArmTestDev' is not defined in the template.`

The parent template: (top two deployments are the ones causing issue)

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "resourcegroupName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name given to the group and all resources it contains by default"
            }
        },
        "templateFolderUri": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The URI of the template component folder"
            }
        }
    },
    "functions": [],
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('resourceGroupName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "resourceGroup": "[parameters('resourcegroupName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "templateLink": {
                    "uri": "[concat(parameters('templateFolderUri'), '/servicePlanCreator.json')]",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
                }
            }
            
        },
        {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('resourceGroupName'), 'App')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "resourceGroup": "[parameters('resourcegroupName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "templateLink": {
                    "uri": "[concat(parameters('templateFolderUri'), '/dualSlotWebApp.json')]",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
                },
                "parameters": {}
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/deployments', parameters('resourceGroupName'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('resourceGroupName'), 'Storage')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "resourceGroup": "[parameters('resourcegroupName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "templateLink": {
                    "uri": "[concat(parameters('templateFolderUri'), '/storageAccountTemplate.json')]",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
                },
                "parameters": {}
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('resourceGroupName'), 'Vault')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "resourceGroup": "[parameters('resourcegroupName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "templateLink": {
                    "uri": "[concat(parameters('templateFolderUri'), '/keyVaultCreator.json')]",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
                },
                "parameters": {}
            }
        }
        
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

servicePlanCreator:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "servicePlanName": {
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().name]",
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the newly created resource"
                }
        },
        "operatingSystem": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "windows",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The Operating system the the newly created resource will use"
                }
        },
        "sku": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "S1",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The sku (pricing tier) the resource group the service plan will use"
            }
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().Location]",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "(Optional) The location og the resource. Will default to the location of the resource group if not set."
            }
        }
    },
    "functions": [],
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('servicePlanName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
            "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "kind": "[parameters('operatingSystem')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('sku')]"
            },
            "tags": {},
            "properties": {
                "name": "[parameters('servicePlanName')]"
            }
            
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

dualSlotWebApp template:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "webAppName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[concat(resourceGroup().name)]",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "(Optional) Web App name. Defaults to '<ResourceGroupName>Plane' if not supplied"
            }
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "(Optional) Web App name. Defaults to Resource group location if not supplied"
            }
        },
        "appServicePlan": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().name]",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "name of the Service plan the app will be assigned to"
            }
        }
    },
    "functions": [],
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('webAppName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "apiVersion": "2020-12-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "name": "[parameters('webAppName')]",
                "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('appServicePlan'))]"
            },
            "resources": [
                {
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('webAppName'), '/Slot1')]",
                    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/slots",
                    "apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
                    "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
                    "dependsOn": [
                        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('webAppName'))]"
                    ],
                    "tags": {
                        "displayName": "Web Deploy for webApp1"
                    },
                    "properties": {
                        "packageUri": "[concat('artifactsLocation', '/WebPackages/webApp1.zip', 'artifactsLocationSasToken')]",
                        "dbType": "None",
                        "connectionString": "",
                        "setParameters": {
                            "IIS Web Application Name": "webApp1"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

Comment: Is this problem related to or caused by the problem in an earlier question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72406771/how-to-deploy-a-arm-template-with-linked-template-that-contains-a-resource-group ?

Comment: Yes I later realised there was another problem I was having in my Arm templates regarding creating dependencies between linked templates. This question is for the same set of template however this problem is in the parent template whereas the previous one was for the 'grandparent' template

Comment: The problems are independent, just both happening in the same set of templates

Comment: I think if you apply the fix from the other question, the problem you're seeing here should go away. I was able to apply the fix and was able to deploy the app service plan. If you're seeing a different error, update this question with the different error message.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the error in this question is different. In the previous question the error was that the linked template above this one (grandparent) could not convert the parameters to the correct type because I had input them incorrectly. The error in this question is due to dependencies. The dependency I have used in the parent template between the linked app and service plan are causing the issue. The error is saying that the service plan deployment is not defined in the template and I do not understand why.

Comment: I have edited the language in the question to be more consistent with the first question. the parent template in this question is the same (slightly altered) as the parent (mid level) template in the previous question. In the previous question the problem was in the 'grandparent' template. Deploying this parent template directly gives the above error, and now that you fixed the 'grandparent' template it too throws the same error (as expected), so I still need a fix to the error in this question. When I wrote the first question I hadn't noticed the mistake in the parent template. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing the templates from your earlier question, it appeared that the `dependsOn` was not configured correctly.

Originally, it was setup incorrectly with:

```
"[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups/', parameters('resourceGroupName'))]"
```

I updated in two places to use the same deployment name:

```
"[concat(parameters('resourceGroupName'), 'ServicePlan')]"
```

The two sections look like:

```
  "resources": [

...

    {
      "name": "[concat(parameters('resourceGroupName'), 'ServicePlan')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "resourceGroup": "[parameters('resourcegroupName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[concat(parameters('templateFolderUri'), '/servicePlanCreator.json')]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        }
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups/', parameters('resourceGroupName'))]"
      ]
    },

...

    {
      "name": "[concat(parameters('resourceGroupName'), 'App')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "resourceGroup": "[parameters('resourcegroupName')]",
      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "uri": "[concat(parameters('templateFolderUri'), '/dualSlotWebApp.json')]",
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
        },
        "parameters": {}
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat(parameters('resourceGroupName'), 'ServicePlan')]"
      ]
    }
  ],
```

Setting the dependency as I have ensures that the service plan **completes** deployment before the app begins deployment.
[image]

Comment: Great that worked, thanks so much. I don't suppose you are able to explain why it is that the previous dependency didn't work as this seems to be the method used in the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates?tabs=azure-powershell#dependencies

Comment: It may have had something to do with the deployment name being the same as the resource group name. When I review the deployment history, there are two entries with the same name but the deployment 'type' is different. `Microsoft.Resources/deployments` and `Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups`. In my work, I try to ensure the deployment names are different.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I will keep my deployment names unique as best practice from now on